# How to calculate Moving Average calculations in Dataset Datatable by C#?

Tags: c#, ado.net, datatable, dataset

Is there any way to do moving average calculations in Dataset Datatable. Is this the best option for calculating moving average calculations by using C sharp? what i am thinking is Datatable looks like excel, because of i am very familier with Excel and vba macros i think this is the best options. I am just beginer in C sharp i don't know other options, so anyone have any information about it, it will very helpful for me. And thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Something as simple as this could do the trick.

```
static class Extensions
{
     public static IEnumerable<double> MovingAverage(this double[] numbers, int runs)
     {
         for (var i = 0; i < numbers.Length - runs + 1; i++)
             yield return Enumerable.Range(i, runs).Average(idx => numbers[idx]);
     }
}
```

Use case:

```
 foreach (var number in new[] {1d, 2d, 7d, 4d, 5}.MovingAverage(2))
     Console.WriteLine(number);
```

Comment: Thaks for your reply. But i couldn't understand this code, can you explain little bit or give me any link about this, that will be helpful.